# What is the interpretation of the following optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Suppose we have $N$ variables $x_1,\ldots,x_N$.
Let $\mathbf{A}$ a $M \times N$ matrix, and $\mathbf{b}$ a $M \times 1$ vector.
 I have the following minimization problem:
\begin{array}{rl}
\min \limits_{\mathbf{x}} & 1  \\
\mbox{s.t.} & \mathbf{Ax}=\mathbf{b}\\ & \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{1}=1 \\ & x_n >0, \forall n
\end{array}
What is the interpretation of this kind of optimization problems?
can we replace $1$ by another constant?

Comment: Yes, you can replace 1 by any constant. This is called a feasibility problem.

Comment: @littleO  Any idea how does it work? I mean how Maltab proceeds to solve this? thank you!

Comment: See http://de.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linprog.html. You need the Optimization Toolbox. There are also interfaces for GLPK and gurobi (free for academic use) around.

Comment: If we replace the positivity constraint with a non negativity constraint, this feasibility problem is a linear program, and linear programs are often solved using interior point methods, or a simplex method. It could also be solved using proximal algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to find if there's a convex combination of the columns of $A$ that will yield $b$.

Any feasible solution to your problem produces such a combination.

Answer (score 0):

It's a *feasibility problem* which has been formulated in a rather odd way. It's simply asking to a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$ s.t $Ax = b$, $\sum_{k}x_k = 1$ and $x_k > 0$  $\forall k$.